# How to install pyusb on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, pyusb

I tried [this link](http://zombiebrainzjuice.fr/pyusb-install-on-ubuntu-homework/), but got the following message on shell:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip` :

```
vineet@vineet:~$ sudo pip install --upgrade pyusb
Downloading/unpacking pyusb
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyusb 
(from versions: 1.0.0a2,   1.0.0a2, 1.0.0a3, 1.0.0a3, 1.0.0b1)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pyusb  
Storing complete log in /home/vineet/.pip/pip.log
```

I want to use pyusb 1.0(or above,if it exists(i am a newbie)) which is written in python. Also will I need `libusb` to run `pyusb`? Please tell me how to download that too! I have tried an failed in both cases.I am using Ubuntu 13.10 so please respond accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `--pre`

```
pip install --pre pyusb
```

The `--pre` flag tells pip to install pre-releases, as pyusb has not reached stable a release yet (1.0.0b2 = beta2).

Update: PyUSB is now stable, you can install simply with `pip install pyusb`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok..I found the answer myself.

I found [this link](http://wiki.erazor-zone.de/wiki%3aprojects%3apython%3apyusb%3asetup%3alinux) wherein the whole procedure is outlined.Providing a gist here:

1.Download,extract and install libusb 1.0.9 from here:[link](http://www.libusb.org/)

2.Download,extract and install pyusb 1.0 from here :[link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/). This link also contains a link to a tutorial for pyusb.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

First install libusb: sudo apt-get install python libusb-1.0-0

Then install pyusb: [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyusb/) and extract. 
Go into the pyusb directory: cd /usr/lib/python2.7/pyusb-1.0.0b2/
From there, run the setup.py (./setup.py, or python setup.py) with the argument install. Should look like this $ sudo ./setup.py install

This should all be done as root user (use sudo).

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old thread and OP asked about Ubuntu 13.10 but for future visitors, `pyusb` is available from `apt` since 14.04. See [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=pyusb).